What is the recommended way for using AddIdentity and AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp together in an asp.net core mvc application?
We're creating an application where the user can log in using username/password or as an alternative use an external IDP like Microsoft Entra.
Before support for the external IDP was added, the application was using Identity, which is added with the following code in the Startup class:
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
     {
         options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
         options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
     })
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>()
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

In order to add support for Microsoft Entra we've added the following code in the saem Startup class:
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
        {
            options.Instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
            options.TenantId = "common";
            options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            options.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.SaveTokens = false;

            options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                // Extract tenantId from the token payload
                var tenantId = context.SecurityToken.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == "tid")?.Value;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tenantId))
                {
                    // Add tenantId as a claim
                    var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("tenantId", tenantId));
                }
                await Task.CompletedTask;
            };

        }, openIdConnectScheme: "Microsoft", cookieScheme: null);

We would like the Microsoft Entra scheme to use the same cookie as Identity uses. By setting cookiescheme to null and handling the sign in ourselves it seems to work.
Setting coookiescheme to IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme makes sense to me, but that does not work.
cookieScheme: IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme

This gives the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Scheme already exists:
Identity.Application'

Another question we have is whether this approach is recommended or should we use another approach?
